# What can we conclude from each description of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$A$ is given to us as an $n × n$ matrix where $z \in R$, and $A*x=z$ has more than one solution.

Now following this are a bunch of either true or false statements about linear independence, linear transformation, etc;

- The columns of $A$ are linearly independent
- The columns of $A$ do not span $\mathbb{R}^n$
- The equation $Ax=y$ is inconsistent for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$
- The columns of $A$ are linearly dependent
- The linear transformation $x⇝Ax$ is surjective (onto)

Using these statements as a basis for analysis, what should I grasp from the description of the matrix A that may help me to answer question like this in the future? (e.g. the feature of it being square ($n$x$n$) allows me to know what when it comes to linear dependance / invertibility )...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: Let $u, v$ be two distinct vectors where $Au = z$, and $Av = z$. What can you say about $A(u - v)$ and what does that imply about the linear dependence of the columns of A?

Comment: Well I know for a matrix with infinitely many solution (which I imagine this case applies), Z must not have a pivot columns, as well as the matrix A cannot have all pivot columns (at least 1 npc). So I guess from this deduction, A's columns are linearly dependant?

Comment: Yeah! Another way to say it is $A(u-v) = Au - Av = z -z = 0$. So the columns of $A$ must be linearly dependent since we found a linear relation of them.

Comment: Considering this fact, can I conclude that the columns cannot span Rn (as they would all have to be pivots), as well as the linear transformation cannot be surjective as if the columns do not span Rn, then, an "onto" transformation is impossible?